# Is there any way to get non-Class Skills as class skills without Multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, skills

I want to get the skills "Knowledge (Planes)" and "Use Psionic Device" on a Kobold Wilder so that:

1. He can Prestige into Anarchic Initiate
2. I can use Dorje that have Powers that aren't on my class list.

I don't want to weaken my manifesting level by multiclassing and can't take Education, as I am not human, or on Faerun for that matter, and it is a Faerunian Regional feat.

Hopefully this is possible through the use of feats. If not it's going to take a long time to get into Initiate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many. I usually use [this list](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=6832.0) myself.

For Knowledge (Psionics), there are many options: Education (*Eberron Campaign Setting* version) gets all of them, and Apprentice (philosopher or spellcaster) (*Player’s Handbook II*) or Knowledge Devotion (*Complete Champion*) gets any of them.

Use Psionic Device is harder, though. There’s Skill Knowledge (*Unearthed Arcana*) but that’s dependent on DM allowing it even if you aren’t using the variant rules that introduce it. The Flexible Mind feat that @Novian found also could work.

But a much **better** answer would be to ask your DM for a Manifester option on the Apprentice feats. Apprentice (Spellcaster) gets you any Knowledge, and Use Magic Device. Apprentice (Manifester) would therefore get you any Knowledge, and Use Psionic Device. Totally appropriate, and much better. Plus it turns into a mini-leadership at level 5, which is cool. The Apprentice feats are solid.

For the Anarchic Initiate, my first advice is to burn your copy of *Complete Psionics*; it’s almost-entirely awful. Barring that, I’d tear out the pages with the Anarchic Initiate. And if you won’t do *that*, hopefully at least your DM is smart enough to see that it’s really dumb that Psions get in far more easily than Wilders and change the pre-reqs.

Comment: its one of the few Prestiges that fit Wilders. Wilder is a Limited class sure but it can have its benefits. If you can suggest a better Psionic Prestige Please come into chat and discuss it with me.

Answer (score 9):

There's a clause in the 3.5 PHB that says you may switch or include different skills as class skills based on your background, but as with all things: when you go off the map, the DM has the final word. (The example in the book is a fighter who is a thieves guild bouncer and gets a few rogue skills enabled)

Edit 1:

> ### Customizing Your Character
>
> (*D&D PHB v3.5, page 110*)
>
> "Some classes already give you plenty of room to customize your character. With your DM's approval, however, you could change some of your character's class features.  For instance, if you want a fighter who used to work for the thieves guild as an enforcer but who is now trying to become a legitimate bodyguard, he could be proficient only with the weapons and armor available to rogues, have 4 skill points per levels instead of 2, and access to Bluff and Sense Motive as class skills.  Otherwise he would be a regular fighter"

Comment: Might I ask Which Page?

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 5):

I foud a solution and thought I would Add this Myself as an answer. The Feats Flexible Mind and Education are the Solutions to this problem.

Flexible Mind Requires that you have ranks in the chosen skills but makes those chosen skills Always class skills. so take 1 cross class rank of 2 skills and once you get this feat take more. it also Gives a +1 bonus to those two skills. it also has the strange side effect of being an anarchic feat. it causes you to radiate a Aura of Chaos much like a Chaotic cleric.

http://www.realmshelps.net/cgi-bin/featbox.pl?feat=Flexible_Mind

The Feat Education(The Eberron Version) is practically the same as the other two versions of the feat except that it doesn't require a region or a race just that you be 1st level. and instead of a +2 to 2 Knowledge it only gives +1 to two knowledge.

http://www.realmshelps.net/cgi-bin/featbox.pl?feat=Education_%28E%29

Comment: On a side note Realmshelps Feats finder is a useful tool. Has more feats than you could shake a +5 Vorpal Sword at.